# How can I get false values when single if statement is true?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

Sorry if this is repeated question.  This is my first time on StackOverflow.  I'm also a beginner with Python.

So, here's the code.

```py
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    #your code here
  array = [0, 0] #array[0] for sum of positives.  array[1] for sum of negatives.

  for x in arr:
    if x > 0:
      array[0] = array[0] + x
      print(array)



count_positives_sum_negatives([1,2,3,4,-5])
```

Basically, I want to create an array with count of the sum of positives and sum of negatives.  With a given array, it should return `[10, -5].`  For now, I want to learn and understand something, How can I also get the false value when single if statement is true?  I'm thinking of double if-statements or while loop but is this possible with single if statement?
When if statement condition is true, the array becomes [10, 0] so now I have the sum of positives.  How should I get sum of negatives `-5` which is false value with single if-statement?

Question 2:  Why do I get a single repeated value?  I'm not using `return` to stop the loop so I'm confused by this code.

```py
for x in arr:
    while x > 0:
       print(x) # Print 1 again and again...
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to take into account the case of negative numbers.

Comment: Are you simply looking for `else`?

Comment: `while x > 0:` is an endless loop if nothing inside the loop changes `x`. This is a trivial duplicate and should probably simply be removed from this post. Ask a single question at a time.

Comment: for your first question.. answer is use *else*.... before asking question here I would recommed you to learn basic on any online tutorials

Comment: Yeah, I could do another if-statement with the condition `y < 0` and use it to get negative values.  But I wonder if it is possible to get both true and false values?  Not just true values

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the concept of if statements.  I assumed it's simiar to while loop.  I'm overthinking too much.  I'm take intro to Python course but I just wanted to work ahead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```
if x>0:
   ... 
else:
   ...
```

Additional question: there should be `if`, not `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
for element in array:
    if element > 0:
      aggregation[0] += element
    else:
      aggregation[1] += element
```

If you want compact version:

```
for element in array:
    aggregation[0 if element>0 else 1] += element
```

Comment: There should be index 1 in second case

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is the following, without using if condition at all:

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    #your code here
  array = [0, 0] #array[0] for sum of positives.  array[1] for sum of negatives.

  for x in arr:
     array[int(x<0)] += x
  print(array)



count_positives_sum_negatives([1,2,3,4,-5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I could've answer my own question.

Here it is.

```py
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    #your code here
  array = [0, 0] #array[0] for sum of positives.  array[1] for sum of negatives.

  for x in arr:
    if x > 0:
      array[0] = array[0] + x
    else:
      array[1] = array[1] + x
    print(array)



count_positives_sum_negatives([1,2,3,4,-5])
```

Thanks for the help guys.